Solving projectile motion equation
I came across this projectile motion equation in a text book today
$$
 y = (1 + \sqrt{2}) x - 90 \ln\bigg(\frac{45\sqrt{2}}{45\sqrt{2} - x}\bigg)
$$
The questioned asked to accurately plot the equation and estimate the range (i.e $ y = 0 $).  I have done this and found the range to be $R \approx 44 m$).  However, I would like to solve the equation algebraically, but I don't know where to start.
Any help appreciated.

If $y=a\cdot x+b\cdot \ln\left(\frac{{c}}{d-x}\right)$, then
$$x=-\frac{b\cdot \mathrm{W}! \left(\frac{a c {\mathrm e}^{\frac{a d-y}{b}}}{b}\right)-a d}{a}$$
$\mathrm{W}(z)$ is the Lambert W function.

Thanks gpmath.  Now to brush up on Lambert W functions.

Can you explain how this is derived please?
